# Can we use butter knife and data binding in same project

Tags: android, android-databinding, butterknife

In a old android project we used butter knife to bind data. But currently want to use databinding so update gradle with databinding = true and create new activity with databinding. But after successful build and install app is crash with showing butter knife bind value is null. So do I need to revamp whole project to databinding or any other way to use both butterknife and databinding.

Comment: Both can use the same time,
My current project has both

Comment: @CuongNguyen How to use both in same project?